# htaccess direct all pages and sub directories to index.php

Tags: .htaccess

I'm attempting to get all of the sub directories inside a specific sub directory to load via the index.php file of said directory via its htaccess file. I'm having an issue setting up my .htaccess file correctly.

Directory Path: sitename.com/BLOG/CMS/

My router loads everything to the index.php file in the BLOG directory which is also where its .htaccess file is too, separate from the root sites .htaccess file.

It works for redirecting all of the pages in the blog directory, and any page with a "slug" in it on the CMS directory, like sitename.com/BLOG/CMS/home, but when I go to .com/BLOG/CMS/ in the address bar, with no "slug", it loads the root sites index.php file.

How can I set up my .htaccess file to properly load the BLOG index.php file when visiting .com/BLOG/CMS/ ?

.htaccess for BLOG directory

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```